# iPhone images of lights shows black bars. Double slit experiment?

Tags: experimental-physics

To start: I know I'm pushing the boundaries a little bit, given Stack Exchange's strictly academic context. This question isn't really too academic, so I understand if it needs to be taken down.

The question: I saw this light display at a store and took a picture of it with my iPhone. Two black bars appear, as shown in the image below. This occurred with my other friends' phones as well. The black bars go away when I don't point it at the lights anymore.

I'm not a physics student but I remember reading about the double-slit experiment, and this seems pretty similar. I'm wondering if there's an explanation for why this happens and if comparisons to the double-slit experiment are apt.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Fairly certain that this effect is due to the camera shutter speed, check out the following link to diagnose it: https://phototacopodcast.com/help-why-are-there-black-bars-across-my-photo/

Comment: Double-slit experiment with light applies when the separation between slits is on the order of the wavelength of light. So even if these slits a physical you would not expect to observe the effect because visible light has size of hundreds of nanometres, and the “slits” (camera artefacts) seem separate by tens of centimetres.

Answer (score 2):

This is a probably some sort of artefact, hardware error (damage) or could even be related to a bug in the software used on that device (though the fact that it happened on other phones seems bizarre, unless you are all using the same IOS with the same bug!).

But is not related to the [double slit interference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) effect. For this you would need a source of light (or other particles) which would enter two slits setup so that this beam is split into two seperate ones that then combine ([superposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference)).

Because these two beams will have different path lengths, an interference pattern will form on a screen set a distance from the two slits.